# Displaying Page Numbers with django-tables2

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I'm currently displaying a dataset using django-tables2.

The docs make no mention of this in particular, so I'm guessing this'll take probably some table overriding - but, I'm hopeful someone out there has already accomplished this.

How can I render page numbers using django-tables2 below my table? What I'd like to be able to display is a horizontal list of page numbers that the user can click.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you need to create a custom page rendering template - you don't need to override any classses.

To do that, start by copying the file

```
PYTHON\Lib\site-packages\django_tables2\templates\django_tables2\table.html
```

to the `templates` directory inside your django application and rename it to `mytable.html` or whatever else you like.

Now, you need to change the *pagination* block of that file. There are many ways to do what you like, but a simple way is to add the following lines inside the pagination block (you may remove or keep the other things that are there depending on your specific needs):

```
{% block pagination.allpages %}
  {% for p in table.paginator.page_range %}
    <a href="{% querystring table.prefixed_page_field=p %}">{{ p }}</a>
  {% endfor %}
{% endblock pagination.allpages %}
```

Finally, to use your template, just pass your custom template name to the render_table command:

```
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
...
{% render_table table "mytable.html" %}
```

This is very simple and will give you trouble if you have many pages (so you have to use some `if`s to check the number of pages through the `table.paginator.num_pages` variable). Also, you may highlight the current page and disable the link by using the  `table.page.number` variable.

The above are left as an excersise to the reader :)

Comment: Thanks! I actually ended up resolving this myself by installing bootstrap-pagination and writing my own pagination function. However, upboated for the response and specificity.

Answer (score 5):

Improving on @Serafeim answer (or solving the exercise he left): Here is a pagination block which, using only Django template syntax, renders page numbers that:

- are enclosed in a `<ul>` HTML block, whith CSS classes that "play well" with Bootstrap;
- if there are more than 8 pages, at most 3 pages below and above current page are shown;
- first and last pages are always shown, with ellipsis between them and the start or end of the range (if needed).

  ```
   {% with current_page=table.page.number page_count=table.paginator.num_pages rows_per_page=table.page.object_list|length total_rows=table.page.paginator.count %}
   {% block pagination %}
   <ul class="pagination">
       {% block pagination.allpages %}
           <li class="current">
               {% blocktrans %}Page {% endblocktrans %}
           </li>
           {% for page in table.paginator.page_range %}
               {% with range_start=current_page|add:"-3" range_end=current_page|add:"3" page_count_minus_5=page_count|add:"-5" page_count_minus_1=page_count|add:"-1" %}
                   {% if page == current_page %}
                       <li class="active">
                           <span>{{ page }}</span>
                       </li>
                   {% elif page == 1 or page >= range_start and page <= range_end or page == page_count %}
                       <li class="next">
                           <a href="{% querystring table.prefixed_page_field=page %}">{{ page }}</a>
                       </li>
                   {% endif %}
                   {% if page == 1 and current_page > 5 or page == page_count_minus_1 and current_page <= page_count_minus_5 %}
                       <li class="current">...</li>
                   {% endif %}
               {% endwith %}
           {% endfor %}
       {% endblock pagination.allpages %}

       {% block pagination.cardinality %}
           <li class="cardinality">
               {% if total_rows != rows_per_page %}{% blocktrans %}
                   {{ rows_per_page }} of {{ total_rows }}{% endblocktrans %}
               {% else %}
                   {{ total_rows }}
               {% endif %} 
               {% if total_rows == 1 %}
                   {{ table.data.verbose_name }}
               {% else %}
                   {{ table.data.verbose_name_plural }}
               {% endif %}
           </li>
       {% endblock pagination.cardinality %}
   </ul>
   {% endblock pagination %}
   {% endwith %}
  ```

Comment: The 'pagina' variable in the line '{% if page == 1 and current_page > 5 or pagina...' should probably be 'page'.  I tested with that change and it seems to work as expected but I wasn't able to edit the answer myself since it's less than a 6 character change.

Comment: @lxmmxl56 You're right, my mistake... That's what happens when you translate your variable names to English, and don't test the code. Corrected. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Pagination is introduced in version# >= 2.0.0
https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/CHANGELOG.html

Simply add following code in settings.py. Pagination with number will be rendered with bootstap 4 style. Make sure you have bootstrap 4 reference in html template.

```
DJANGO_TABLES2_TEMPLATE = 'django_tables2/bootstrap4.html'
```

And check out more styles in documentation.
https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-rendering.html#available-templates

Comment: This only changes the style of the table( not the paginator )

Comment: FYI as of v2.4.1 if your table's `Meta` class overrides `template_name` this will take precedent over whatever is defined in `settings.py`. See the relevant section in the source [code](https://github.com/jieter/django-tables2/blob/v2.4.1/django_tables2/tables.py#L152)